# 404 Not found - consume the Web API by angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have my controller code:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Email")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByEmail(string email)
    {
        Users user = db.Users.Find(email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
    }
```

and my WebApiConfig:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "EmailApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{email}",
            defaults: new { email = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
}
```

and finally  my js code

```
$http.get('/api/users/Email/' + NewUser.Email)      
         .success(function (response) {
             console.log(response);                  // prints 404 not found 
         });
```

The problem is that I get response (404 not found ) for the searched email although it exists in the email field in the Users table.

Comment: try changing `$http.get` call to `$http.get('/api/users/Email?email=' + NewUser.FullName)`

Comment: Things to check - 1) Have you registered Web API Routes in Global.asax? 2) can you post use complete route config for web api?

Comment: @pankajparkar : that gave me internal server error (http://localhost:54233/api/Users/Email?email=abc@gmail.com 500 (Internal Server Error))

Comment: @ ramiramilu : You are good. I am actually beginner to Routing just today. Please let me know how to do that in Global.asax? Also,  I will edit my post for the complete config for web api.

Comment: @AbuTaha try `        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "EmailApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/users/Email/{email}",
            defaults: new { email = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );` this route

Comment: @ pankajparkar : Unfortunately, 500 error. GET http://localhost:54233/api/Users/Email?email=abc@gmail.com 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: check the controller name, is your api controller name UsersController?

Comment: I replicated your code and I was not getting any error. Did you have - `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfige.Register)`?

Comment: @ ramiramilu . Good news sir. No I do not have it.Go back to my above WebApiConfig.cs and check ..  Where to put that sir?  thank you

Comment: @ramiramilu yes I have the GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) at my global.asax.cs

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it:

```
    public Users Get(string Email)
    {
        Users user = db.Users.Find(Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return user;
    }
```

No need for rout

Answer (score 0):

the route request an id but you send a string
change the routeTemplate to

```
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
```

Comment: thank you for reply. But the error still there: http://localhost:54233/api/Users/Email/abc@gmail.com 404 (Not Found)

Comment: if you are sure the above email exists in the db.
add line: string email = email.ToLower(); or debug the code to check what value the 'user' returns.

Comment: I am sure. I also sued the ToLower() in c#. I am also using the browser debug as you see in my code above:    console.log(response);

Comment: try checking postman to see if there are any clues, no different from the normal way but just avoid dependency on any other thing, and execute request independently. 
Also may be the special characters are not allowed @, . Try and see to allow those in your routing.

Comment: A quick suggestion. I would try to return a a proper error message instead of returning a NotFound in the event of email is unavailable. It causes unnecessary confusion. Does not help you answer the question may be.

Comment: @ Immortal no sensitivity for the symbols '@' . According to what you said about postman and independent request execution, I do not have idea ho I can achieve that.

Comment: Look for a rest client chrome extension. you can call the api from there with suitable request parameters. it renders the output or server error number which helps in debugging.

Comment: @ Dev-One  I installed the chrome rest client. It is amazing. so far I got this JSON message: {
Message: "An error has occurred."
ExceptionMessage: "Multiple actions were found that match the request: Get on type TakamulTest.Controllers.UsersController Email on type TakamulTest.Controllers.UsersController"
}